# How can I insert new item on a list<> checking id for duplicates?

Tags: c#, list, uwp, duplicates

I have to make a list of runners and the user cannot insert a runner that has the same Id of another runner (which has been inserted).

I tried with this:

```
async private void save_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int flag = 0;
        if (dni.Text != "")
        {
            Corredor co = new Corredor();

            flag = 0;   
            co.Dni = dni.Text;
            co.Nombre = nombreCorredor.Text;
            co.Apellidos = apellidos.Text;
            co.ClubDeportivo = clubDeportivo.Text;
            co.FechaNacimiento = new DateTime(pickerFechaNacimiento.Date.Year, pickerFechaNacimiento.Date.Month, pickerFechaNacimiento.Date.Day);
            if(federado.IsChecked == true)
            {
                co.Federado = true;
            }
            else
            {
                co.Federado = false;
            }
            
            

            foreach (Corredor rec in App.lCorredores)
            {

                if (string.Equals(rec.Dni, co.Dni))
                {
                    flag = 1;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    flag = 0;

                }


            }
            if (flag == 0)
            {
                App.lCorredores.Add(co);
                MessageDialog md = new MessageDialog("Corredor Añadido");
                await md.ShowAsync();
                Limpiar_v();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageDialog mde = new MessageDialog("Ese corredor ya existe");
                await mde.ShowAsync();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageDialog md = new MessageDialog("Debe rellenar los datos");
            await md.ShowAsync();
        }
    }
```

but once I insert a duplicated id (Dni) the program just shows me the error again and again. And I can't keep adding items.

I can't see the error here.

Comment: You can try using a different data structure, such as a Dictionary or a Hashtable. Add the data on the collection using its Key member, checking if one already exists beforehand.

Comment: I can't use any other different data stucture

Comment: @0asir can you change the type of `lCorredores` to `HashSet<T>`?

Comment: What exactly is the error message?

Answer (score 1):

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var tst = new TestClass { Id = 1 };

            var lst = new List<TestClass> { new TestClass { Id = 1 } };

            if (lst.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == tst.Id) == null)
            {
                lst.Add(tst);
            }
            else
            {
                // code that maust run is already exists
            }
        }
    }

    class TestClass
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Use dictionaries in this case, they have TryAdd() methothod that can be useful.

Not checked but try to do this way:

```cs
async private void save_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (dni.Text != "")
    {
        var co = new Corredor
        {
            Dni = dni.Text,
            Nombre = nombreCorredor.Text,
            Apellidos = apellidos.Text,
            ClubDeportivo = clubDeportivo.Text,
            FechaNacimiento = new DateTime(pickerFechaNacimiento.Date.Year, pickerFechaNacimiento.Date.Month, pickerFechaNacimiento.Date.Day),
            Federado = federado.IsChecked,
        };
                

        if (App.lCorredores.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Dni == co.Dni) == null)
        {
            App.lCorredores.Add(co);
            MessageDialog md = new MessageDialog("Corredor Añadido");
            await md.ShowAsync();
            Limpiar_v();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageDialog mde = new MessageDialog("Ese corredor ya existe");
            await mde.ShowAsync();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageDialog md = new MessageDialog("Debe rellenar los datos");
        await md.ShowAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: The program shows the same. First item, success. The next, the error, again and again

Comment: What do you mean? App shows you a new message after you close previous one or what?

Comment: The app shows, the first time, that the item it's successfully insert ("MessageDialog md = new MessageDialog("Corredor Añadido");"). But, the next times, shows the error message that means there is another item with the same Id. ( MessageDialog mde = new MessageDialog("Ese corredor ya existe");)

Comment: And what you want? If runner with that Dni exists, so error occurs, change the Dni in input field and it will be inserted. If it is not behaviour you want, then ask auestion in another way

Comment: When I try to insert a new item with a different dni, the same message appears. Sorry if I didn't explain it in a better way.

Comment: Looks like `dni.Text` always the same and is not changing 2+ times. Put a breakpoint at `if (dni.Text != "")` line and check that `dni.Text` changes at the second button click.